# Biblical basis for treating a second marriage as sinful even in cases of adultery?

Tags: biblical-basis, marriage, adultery

| Matthew 19:9 (NIV) |
| --- |
| I tell you that anyone who divorces his wife, except for sexual immorality, and marries another woman commits adultery. |

Many Christians believe it is okay to remarry if a previous marriage ended due to adultery. However, there are Pentecostal strands in my country that regard any second marriage as sinful and adulterous regardless of whether the prior marriage was dissolved due to spousal infidelity. Is there a biblical basis for this view, especially one focused on Matthew 19:9? one of the strongest arguments is that the word sexual immorality refers to fornication with the current woman, that is, there is no marriage, so it would not be a sin to marry another woman because the individual would be in fornication with the current woman, but this translation uses "divorce" not "separate", presuming a previous marriage with his atual woman.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Scripture does not condemn a man having two wives. What is condemned is a man evicting and divorcing one wife in order to take another. Adultery is not in view in that context. If a woman commits adultery with a man other than her husband, her husband may divorce her. What is your question about these very clear matters ?

Comment: I've rewritten this to hopefully be more intelligible. Hopefully I have not changed the intent; if not, I apologize and please feel free to revert. (Unfortunately my rep is such that edits skip the proposal stage.) I also dropped the first paragraph, as I don't think it adds anything after the other clarifications.

Comment: Off topic: Davi, I notice you've posted a number of questions regarding beliefs that I think many Christians would consider... questionable. Might I suggest that, rather than trying to justify your current beliefs, you might want to take a good hard look at them, and possible find a different church / different theological circle?

Comment: Sorry @Matthew I see no reason for people referring some theological cicle, each theological cicle is just a set of human subjectivisms that converge to a certain idea, I'm trying to understand the bible in the purest and least objective way possible

Comment: but yes, I'm trying to formalize the theology that I've always been preached, but I have to do it in the most objective way possible.

Comment: "trying to understand the bible in the purest and least objective way possible". I hope you meant "*most* objective", which would be a laudable goal, and sort of my point; your current understanding seems to be... uncommon. However, you seem to be trying to defend your current beliefs, rather than trying to establish what the Bible *actually* says, i.e. [eisegesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisegesis) rather than exegesis. Eisegesis is a very bad way to arrive at genuine truth. (Could we continue this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room)?)

Comment: I'm trying to use pure objectivism to defend what I've been saying.

Comment: Objectiveism is an idealistic philosophy that affirms and celebrates the human capacity for achievement and heroism. It supposedly provides a secular meaning for religious concepts such as exaltation, worship and reverence. May I ask how this is relevant within the context of the Christian religion?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivism

Answer (score 1):

## Some people believe that "except for infidelity" was a later addition.

Simply put, there are groups of Christians who believe that Jesus banned divorce entirely, and the "except for infidelity" clause was inserted by later scribes as a way of softening Jesus's words.

After all, immediately after Jesus says this, the disciples who hear it are shocked at how limited Jesus had made the requirements of divorce. This wouldn't make sense if he allowed divorce in response to adultery, since at the time, there was a debate between two camps of rabbis on whether divorce was only allowable in response to adultery, or if a husband could divorce his wife for any reason. If Jesus was just supporting one camp of rabbis over another, would that really have been so unexpected?

Comment: **”Some people believe that "except for infidelity" was a later addition.”** Could you add a link to support this thought?

Comment: @KenGraham It's something I remember reading about a while ago, bud I couldn't find a source when I went looking  though I did find some stuff talking about the debate between the two rabbis.

Comment: I don't recall the "later insertion" hypothesis being raised, but the mention of the rabbis' opinions reminds me that Mike Winger has a good (series of?) video(s) on divorce and remarriage. Probably worth a watch for anyone interested in the matter.